# Group such that $a^n=1$ for all $a$

Tags: group-theory

Could you help me to find a group $G$ with the following property:

$\exists \;n < \; |G|$ such that $\forall a \in G : a^n=1$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Any group that is any number of "outer products" of cyclic groups will have this property. It's probably not called outer product, my algebra vocabulary is very small.

Comment: Any finite group satisfies $a^{|G|}=1$, so you can take $n=|G|$. EDIT: This was a comment to a previous version of the question.

Comment: The easiest example is $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 5):

Try working through the smallest groups you know. There is (up to isomorphism) one of size $1$, but that one doesn't satisfy your condition. Neither do the two groups of size $2$ and $3$.

For size $4$, you have two groups available. One of them satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Any non-identity element has order 2 here, but the order of the group is 4. You can try with many other products of finite cyclic group. But not any, since when the order of the groups are coprime, you will have elements of order the order of the group (check that!).

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fermat's little theorem from elementary number theory, for any integer $a$ and the prime number $p$ we have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 (\text{mod }p) $. Take the modulo-p group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with elements $\{0,1,\cdots,p-1\}$ with cardinality $|G|=p$, for any element of this group we have $a^{p-1}=1$.